# Should we copy (re-ask) the Area51 DevOps-related **discussions** here?

Tags: discussion

IMHO several of the Area51 [meta-style discussions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295?phase=definition) related to the DevOps proposal during its definition phase are still quite relevant and would very well belong here.

Should we copy/ask them here as well? Together with the answers or just with a reference to the original (which also has the answers)?

Comment: Could you check whether some Q&As could still be copied? Please let me know if I could help.

Comment: Certainly, but when I get back from vacation, in about 2 weeks. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Some of these were re-asked here again in some fashion. It would be better imho to have it all in a single place though.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO these discussions (maybe not with all answers) would still be worthy candidates for migration/copy here today:

- [On why having a DevOps q&a website would be useful for many](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20280/on-why-having-a-devops-qa-website-would-be-useful-for-many)
- [How do we help visitors to ask their question on an appropriate SE site, while implementing a welcoming and benevolent attitude?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21783/how-do-we-help-visitors-to-ask-their-question-on-an-appropriate-se-site-while-i)
- [Do we discuss here as well the about the good practises on how to build the right mindset/cultural in a organisation?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26171/do-we-discuss-here-as-well-the-about-the-good-practises-on-how-to-build-the-right)
- [Would Devops-related SW recommendations be on-topic on DevOps?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/would-devops-related-sw-recommendations-be-on-topic-on-devops)
- [DevOps Site Description- too narrow?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26466/devops-site-description-too-narrow)

Some of them would need edits as the site is now a reality, unless we indicate the context.

How do we go about it (if there's agreement on doing it, of course)?